# the Name of Function defined in C

Tags: debug, defun, source

I tried to use `GDB` to debug Emacs.  
More specifically, I want to observe the behavior of a function written in C.

> `vertical-motion` is **a *built-in* function in ‘C source code’**.

However, the name of a C function cannot contain a `-` (i.e., *minus sign*).  
So `GDB` will complain when I type `break vertical-motion`.

I noticed that this function is defined by `DEFUN` (C macro?), which is weird to me:

```c
DEFUN ("vertical-motion", Fvertical_motion, Svertical_motion, 1, 3, 0,
       doc: /* ... */)
  (Lisp_Object lines, Lisp_Object window, Lisp_Object cur_col)
{ ... }
```

What is a *built-in* function's C name?  
(including those NOT defined by `DEFUN` if they exist)

Comment: "*C macro?*" --- Or Emacs maintainers wrote a pre-processor specifically for Emacs C source code?  (That may not be the point.  I'm just mentioning it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C function name is `Fvertical_motion`.

`DEFUN` is a macro defined in lisp.h.  It is used to define C functions which are also visible as lisp functions.

```
/* Define a built-in function for calling from Lisp.
 `lname' should be the name to give the function in Lisp,
    as a null-terminated C string.
 `fnname' should be the name of the function in C.
    By convention, it starts with F.
 `sname' should be the name for the C constant structure
    that records information on this function for internal use.
    By convention, it should be the same as `fnname' but with S instead of F.
    It's too bad that C macros can't compute this from `fnname'.
 `minargs' should be a number, the minimum number of arguments allowed.
 `maxargs' should be a number, the maximum number of arguments allowed,
    or else MANY or UNEVALLED.
    MANY means there are &rest arguments.  Here we pass a vector
        of evaluated arguments in the form of an integer
        number-of-arguments followed by the address of a vector of
        Lisp_Objects which contains the argument values.  (We also use
        this convention when calling a subr with more than 8 parameters.)
    UNEVALLED means pass the list of unevaluated arguments
 `intspec' says how interactive arguments are to be fetched.
    If the string starts with a `(', `intspec' is evaluated and the resulting
    list is the list of arguments.
    If it's a string that doesn't start with `(', the value should follow
    the one of the doc string for `interactive'.
    A null string means call interactively with no arguments.
 `doc' is documentation for the user.  */

/* This version of DEFUN declares a function prototype with the right
   arguments, so we can catch errors with maxargs at compile-time.  */
#define DEFUN(lname, fnname, sname, minargs, maxargs, intspec, doc) \
...
```

If you search the C code for `Fvertical_motion` you will also find many direct calls to that name.

Comment: But there is a `doc: /* ... */` in the `DEFUN` form.  Can C macro process comments?

Comment: I think that `lib-src/make-docfile.c` is responsible for extracting those docstring comments.  (That's as far as I've ever looked into it, though, and I've only done so just now :)

Comment: So the technique here is something like what I mentioned in my [another comment](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/76542/the-name-of-function-defined-in-c/76543?noredirect=1#comment126743_76542)?

Comment: Yes - `make-docfile` is invoked by a Makefile with all the source files (and more) of Emacs as arguments . It gets all the doc strings that it finds into `etc/DOC`.  The file is read in at Emacs initialization and then `describe-function` calls `documentation` to fetch the doc string (which is stored as just an index (a number) in the function).  I *think* this is correct, but caveat emptor.

Comment: The C comment for *fname* of `DEFUN` in `src/lisp.h` may be a little incomplete.  In general, it starts with the letter *F* and **uses underscore(s)**.  This is natural, in line with C conventions, but ... for rigor.  [My answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/76542/76563#76563) is an addendum to yours.

Answer (score 3):

Provide a reference (from the *manual*) for [@phils](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/454)'s answer; 
Supplement the conversion convention for the name of the function.

[E.7 Writing Emacs Primitives](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Writing-Emacs-Primitives.html):

> Here is a template for them:
>
> ```c
> DEFUN (lname, fname, sname, min, max, interactive, doc)
> ```
>
> ***lname***
> : This is the name of the Lisp symbol to define as the function name; ...
>
> ***fname***
> : This is the C function name for this function. This is the name that is used in C code for calling the function. **The name is, by convention, ‘`F`’ prepended to the Lisp name, with all dashes (‘`-`’) in the Lisp name changed to underscores.**

---

As for the docstrings in the comments, although they may not be relevant, I just make a note here of one point of interest:

> The others have placeholders beginning with ‘`SKIP`’, which are ignored by **the *function* that parses the `DOC` file**.